# Error happening due to string's length limit?

Tags: string

```
for(int i=1;i<=50;i++)

    {
        s+=to_string(i)+s; 
    }
```

this code's giving error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc" can someone explain why ??

Comment: what language is this? Can you post `to_string(int)`?

Comment: To confirm, the list of strings generated at each iteration will go like this: `1`, `121`, `1213121`, `121312141213121`, ... Notice first that the string doubles in length on each iteration, so the length of the string will be roughly 2^n.  So n = 50 is about a terabyte, and is asking for trouble, don't you think?  I don't have that much RAM, do you? (Is this even what you intended?)

Comment: It looks like C++. Did you define string `s`?

Comment: @Wyck It's a string, not an int, and a string can be very long, so I don't think it would be a problem to store a very long string in RAM.

Comment: @instanceof It's not a problem.  The code is fine.  I'm just pretty sure that the asker doesn't have the terabytes of RAM required to store this string and hence, got the bad_alloc.  More likely they intended either `s = something + s` or `s += something` rather than both `s += something + s`.

Comment: yeah I have defined the string and it's c++

Comment: Oh it depends on ram's capacity ?? and yes I intended to add both, it was a cp problem which had easier solution for real, but I was trying brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some problems with allocation. There is a limit of string size (The maximum size of a string is 9223372036854775807 (pointer size: 64 bits)). Check your code your 's' is increasing exponentially.